# Understanding the datatype Double

Tags: double

I am trying to write a program in C to get the percent of even numbers in an array. I am thinking of writing it using int datatype. But some one mentioned to me using double will be easier. I don't understand that. Can anyone guide me with it?

What does double datatype return? 
Can the return statement be given as return (double)? What will that give?
Can double convert a real number to a percent? Eg: 0.5 to 50.0

Answer (score 0):

The `int` datatype is, as the name would suggest, integers (or whole numbers). So you cannot represent a decimal like `0.5`. A `double` is decimal number. So you can hold numbers like `0.5`. Common practice is to store your percentage as a simple decimal number like `0.5` (using the `double` type). Then when you need to display nicely as `50.0%`, just multiply by `100` before displaying.

Here's a useful link on C's basic datatypes: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_basic_datatypes.htm